# Is it possible to have a single document listener to multiple text fields in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, jtextfield

I have a 12 filters for 12 columns on a JTable. Each filter is a TextField of type JTextField. Every time a user enters the data in the text box filter then search happens.

**Example:**
Suppose say, I have 3 columns and 3 text boxes above them as filters. Now any thing which is typed in any of the text boxes my table filtering has to happen. It is happening great.

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ [TextField] ║ [TextField] ║ [TextField] ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║             ║             ║             ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
      ...           ...           ...
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║             ║             ║             ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Text field listener for each of the text field looks like this,

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { method(); } 
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { method(); }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { method(); } 
};
```

My question is, I am repeating this code for all the 12 text fields, which I was not really happy. Is this the only way we have ? or can some one suggest me a better way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Switch from an anonymous class to an inner class and attach the same listener to each field. The source is contained in the event
- Make it a separate class and keep on using separate listeners for each field. Avoids at least the code duplication

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for an example of an inner class

Comment: +1 .. brilliant .. worked like a charm. No redundacy of code now .. Thanks a lot .. :)

Comment: You can still do this with an anonymous class: `DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() { ... }; for(JTextField textfield : fields) { textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener); }`

Comment: @WalterLaan Can you please post your answer separatly. It helps me to understand other ways of doing this.

Comment: Isn't this again an Inner Class as suggested by @WalterLaan in the comment, anonymous means without name that you cann't reference in future, IMHO. Do stand me corrected, if I am wrong.

Comment: @GagandeepBali no, that is an anonymous class as well. Only you assign it to a variable first so you can add it to multiple documents.

Comment: @Robin : Please have a look at this doc, what it has to say for [Anonymous Inner Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) . What the idea in the comment is pointing to at, is the Local Inner Classes not Anonymous Classes.